# VB.NET How to "Refresh" data DbContext in winform

Tags: vb.net, winforms, entity-framework

I have a `DataDridview` filled with objects queried with my `DbContext`.
I show some basic informations about my objects in this form.

I would like to query the most recent infos from the BD every time I select a different object in the `DataDridview`. I also want to be able to modify these objects.

I'm already able to do that. To modify an object, for example, I will do these steps:
-create a new `DbContext`
-get the object from my Datagridview using `.Selectedrows(0).DatabountItem`
-with that object's id I will query the (most recent) record in the DB using my new `DbContext`
-assign the old object (modified) properties to the new ones, one by one
-`.SaveChanges` on my new `Dbcontext`.

But there has to a better way, right? :/
If I understand correctly, by doing it this way I end up with a ton of unused Dbcontext and I doubt it's best practices.
But whenever I `.Dispose` my context, all EF navigation properties are broken and I get exceptions popping all over the place...  So the ideal solution seems to me to just, refresh the data in a unique DbContext that I would use for the entire form. But is it even possible?

Maybe the solutions is obvious but I just can't see it.

If I'm unclear, please let me know I'll do my best to reformulate.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

** **Edit** **
In the end, here's the solution that worked best for me:
I do create a new DbContext for every logical operation, then immediatly `.Dispose` it...
Except for when I show informations about a specific row in my datagridview.
Instead, I create a new Context and leave it open. I will `.Dispose` only when the `datagridview.SelectionChanged` event fires.

The reason for not Disposing this context immediatly is: If a user saves his changes, but in the meantime someone else also saved changes on the same record, the (not-synced) context will hit a concurrency issue.. and I can let the user know about it, instead of overriding that row, which would be bad.

If I need these navigations properties from EF elsewhere, I can simply do eager loding by `.Include("MyOtherTable")` everything I need.( because navigation properties stop working when a context is Disposed)

Comment: If you are creating a new `DbContext` for every logical operation, you are doing it *correctly*.  Don't create a single context for the entire application, that just leads to problems.  It sounds like you are running in to issues with "Lazy Loading".  You will want to make sure your query completes within the lifetime scope of the context.  Look in to using the `.Include` function to make sure that all the dependent objects are loaded.

Comment: Your comment allowed me to understand Contexts better. I'll do pretty much exactly as you explained here. As for Editing, I will let my context live as long as: the changes haven't been saved or datagridview.SelectedIndexChanged hasn't fired. When either happens, I `MyContext.Dispose()`. Makes sense? :) too bad you didn't respond with an Answer

Comment: That should be fine.  I didn't type up a full answer because I didn't feel that I had enough time to make it as thorough and detailed as it would need to be, but I'm glad that I was able to help you any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use only one context in this case. You must just pay attention for accesing context from another threads - it can result in transaction errors ("New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session")

If you use DataGridView with DataSource from EF Context, all you have to do is just reload entities.
I wrote extension method in my context:

```
public partial class MyContext : testEntities1
{
    public void Refresh(IEnumerable entities)
    {
        var ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
        ctx.Refresh(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, entities);
    }
}
```

it is much faster than  entry.Reload();

F.E.:

```
List<MyEntities> items = new List<MyEntities>();
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows) 
{
    items.Add((MyEntities)row.DataBoundItem);
}
context.Refresh(items);
```

Comment: I get this error:  `The element at index 0 in the collection of objects to refresh has a null EntityKey property value or is not attached to this ObjectStateManager.` I made sure to create a single DbContext at Load, and never re-assign it again..

Comment: Please paste the code you use to attach DataSource in DGV

Comment: The error was caused by `.AsNoTracking` in `(From imp In dbContext.Imprime.AsNoTracking
                    Where imp.imp_num.Contains(numero) AndAlso
                             imp.imp_titre.Contains(titre)
                    Select imp).ToList()`  
which I forgot there at some point while doing tests..
So, right now my DB AND my Datagridview are synced all automagically. Let me understand what's going on lol, and I'll mark your answer as accepted :)

Comment: Using only one `DbContext` instance for the lifetime of the aplication is a huge anti-pattern that practically everyone with any EF experience will tell you to avoid.

Comment: @BradleyUffner i said in this case, previously OP was recreating context each time when an entity was updated.

Comment: @Pascal it works just as it's designed for - DataGridView has entities attached to it and it is also observing them for changes made in your application.

Comment: The code you pasted works as intended, it refreshes the selected row in my dgv. It doesn't fully solves my problem, as I'm still unsure how to manage editing, but thank you anyway. :)

Comment: Having a single context works fine, but it gets complicated when I want to refresh my data... And edit my objects without ending up with several contexts that'll stay attached to my objects but are never really used, nor disposed..? I'll edit my post when I have a definitive solution that works perfectly.
Or, could it be that refreshing my entire dgv with a new context would automatically Dispose all previous contexts?